# How to split data as train and test set in a fixed manner?

Tags: python, cross-validation, accuracy

I've been struggling to figure out the best technique to assess model accuracy in relation to the train/test split.

Leave-one-out cross-validation and KFold appear to be more appropriate to utilize; however, LOOCV does not count more than one row of data as a holdout set, and KFold shuffles the data, preventing it from being in order.
Is there a suitable Python function for this?

Another point is, what is the right method for proving model accuracy?

Note: The data matrix is 900x1015, with one half (450x1015) devoted to one class and the other (450x1015) to another class. I employ two classification models: PCA and PLS-DA. Every three rows in each class contain one sample information, and the samples are in order. Besides, every three rows for one sample are the repeated measurements in different days.

The main picture can be like this;
[image]

Comment: it might be helpful to look at how Time Series modellers do CV; they do things like block CV https://goldinlocks.github.io/Time-Series-Cross-Validation/

Comment: How large is your data set? Whether and how to split depends on that. What type of model are you building? The measure of "accuracy" depends on that. Please provide that information by editing the question, as comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.

Comment: @EdM thanks for the feedback, the question has been edited

Comment: How are the 3 rows for each sample related? Are they repeated measures of the same 1015 characteristics for each sample, say over time? Again, please add that information by editing the question, as you so nicely did in response to my first comment.

Comment: @EdM it is exactly like that! they are repeated measurements, but in different days... so, each row signifies the information collected in different days with the same 1015 characteristics. (the question has been edited.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> LOOCV does not count more than one row of data as a holdout set,

that is what most ready-to-use implementations do by default. However, you could do leave-one-sample-out-CV.

> one half (450x1015) devoted to one class and the other (450x1015) to another class

if you want to preserve the 50:50 relative class frequencies, use **stratification**

> every three rows for one sample are the repeated measurements in different days.

Here it is not yet clear whether random factor measurement (repetition) is nested within random factor sample (patient) or crossed, and whether measurement day is a fixed or random factor. This will depend on your precise application scenario, but correct splitting will depend on this.

- For random measurement days nested within sample, split at the uppermost
  level of the nesting, i.e. sample (as in the question), `GroupKFold()` or `StratifiedGroupKFold()` provide this.
- For random measurement days crossed with sample, you need to produce test sets which are independent both in sample and in measurement day.
  You'll likely set up the splitting yourself and then hand it over to `PredefinedSplit()`
- Other application scenarios (e.g. predict second/third (fixed) measurement from first one/two -> time series treatment) have yet different needs.

Comment: thank you very much! it is really helpful

Answer (score 0):

Try out GroupKFold. It looks like it'll support what you need. If you don't already have a column that groups what you want together, you can make an additional column that identifies what to hold out, e.g. append a column [0,0,0,1,1,...,1] and specify that as your grouping separator. That'll separate your three rows (and sequences of three rows) from the rest of the data.

Check it out [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GroupKFold.html#sklearn.model_selection.GroupKFold)

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback. I will absolutely try this... Are there any additional suggestions for proving the model accuracy of PCA or PLS-DA in another suitable way? I guess hold-out (80% for train, 20% for test) is also the one people most prefer. However, in my case, it can be biased since the data from a patient can be in both train and test sets, which is we do not want this.